# Click and before class function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".items a").click(function(){
         $(".items img").toggleClass("demo-img")
         $("#urun-detay-top-img").html(this)
         e.preventDefault()
    });
});
```

`.items a` clicked need to `toggleClass demo-img` I can do it, but "demo-img" in class has a function. This function is not working. What went wrong?

Comment: `e` is not defined

Answer (score 4):

The only issue I see is that you're calling `e.preventDefault()` but didn't pass event into your callback. Your code should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".items a").click(function(e){  // Notice event passed as argument
         $(".items img").toggleClass("demo-img");
         $("#urun-detay-top-img").html(this);
         e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```